# I want to know, can portable WPF application with Ribbon feature work on windows XP?

Tags: wpf, windows-xp, portable-applications

I want to know, can portable WPF application with Ribbon feature work on windows XP?
If yes then what extra upgrades I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

I have made a WPF application to run in Windows XP and the only thing I had to assure is that the .Net Framework 4.0 was installed.

There are not really problems with Windows XP and ribbon feature.